# Thinktecture Basic Auth WebApi disable on route

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication, thinktecture-ident-model

I have basic auth wired up using Thinktecture to my WebApi.

Is there a way to disable this auth on a single route? Trying to publicly expose a single endpoint.

I'm restricted to WebApi v1, in case that makes a difference in the answer.

Comment: Erm...easiest way...Disable IIS authentication. Only use the `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` on those controllers that need it. Try this [BasicAuthenticationFilter](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter)

Comment: View this for more details http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api